# Unit Testing: C# Assert NullReferenceException not true

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I have the following code I am testing

```
public async Task<obj> foo()
{
    try
    {
        // do something to throw any Exception or in this case NullReferenceException
    }
    catch (Exception ex) // NullReferenceException is caught here and re-thrown
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

and unit test to check that any exceptions in the function are re-thrown. (Yes I know in the code itself it's kind of redundant to re-throw but this is how it's already setup. Just for the sake of this unit test)

```
public async void unit_test() 
{
    // Arrange sut...
    // Act & Assert
    await Assert.ThrowsAsync<Exception>(() => sut.foo());
}
```

The problem is this test is failing because the Expected is typeof(System.Exception) while the Actual is typeof(System.NullReferenceException). But I thought NullReferenceException derives from Exception so should still satisfy the assert?

Comment: Using `throw ex` inside an otherwise empty `catch` is a terrible anti-pattern. What happens is that the current exception is caught (revenge any information about about the original exception). Then a rethrow happens, but without that information as part of the exception. Either use a just-plain `throw;` statement, or rethrow a new exception with the original exception  as the _inner exception_ parameter.

Comment: I believe `Assert.Throws` and `Assert.ThrowsAsync` test for the *exact* exception type you've specified. Sounds like you want `Assert.ThrowsAnyAsync`.

Comment: @Flydog57 yes I know it's not a good practice. This is just how my predecessor setup the code and we're not in a position to be changing it - just trying to do any unit testing for now.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes this is exactly what I need! Just need to catch any and all derived exceptions too.

Comment: If you know its actually a NullReferenceException then i would advise you to test for that. If your test setup fails for what is happening in the try block and throws an exception for that your test will be happy but shouldn't. Typical example is a MockException thrown by a Mock Frameworks.